# Accessing this.props from React Component functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React.js and is confused by how the following 2 functions `displayGender` and `toggleGender` access `this.props` differently.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


export default class User extends Component {

    displayGender() {
        console.log('displayGender: ', this.props)
    }

    toggleGender() {
        console.log('toggleGender: ', this.props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Button onClick={ this.toggleGender.bind(this) } >
                { this.displayGender.bind(this) }
            </Button>
        );
    }
}
```

Why is `this.toggleGender.bind(this)` able to access `this.props` that was passed to this React Component `User`, but `this.displayGender.bind(this)` sees `this.props` as `undefined`?

So far I am only able to access `this.props` from within `this.displayGender` if I pass it to the function. Is this the usual practice?

```
export default class User extends Component {

    displayGender(props) {
        console.log(props.user)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Button onClick={ this.toggleGender.bind(this) } >
                { this.displayGender(this.props) }
            </Button>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: It is rather odd to pass a *function* as a child to a React component. Do you maybe mean to *call* the function (and in the future pass the return value as child)? *"Is this the usual practice?"* If you call the function directly  (i.e. `{this.displayGender()}`) it should be no problem to access `this.props`.

Comment: @FelixKling Can you explain how I am passing a function as a child? Sorry kinda confused here.

Comment: `.bind` returns a function. Hence `{this.displayGender.bind(this)}` passes a function as child to `<Button />`.

Comment: When is displayGender actually called?

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `this.toggleGender.bind(this)` function is added as a `click` event in your component and `this.displayGender.bind(this)` is added as a child  node inside the `<button>`

What bind usually refers is `put the given function inside some other anonymous enclosed function (and preserve the context ie, this if supplied)`

So: `toggleGender.bind(this)` usually refers to `function(){toggleGender()}`

When the above is placed in `click` function it makes sense as we're attaching a function to `click event`. But it wouldn't make sense to add it as a child node

Comment: *"`toggleGender.bind(this)` usually refers to `function(){toggleGender()}`"* I think this is a bit confusing. While `.bind` returns a new function, the fact that `this` is bound to a specific value is important. So rather: `toggleGender.bind(foo)` refers to `function(){toggleGender.call(foo)}`.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for your comment..can you go through my edit and confirm if my assumption is correct?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this.toggleGender.bind(this) able to access this.props that was
>   passed to this React Component User, but this.displayGender.bind(this)
>   sees this.props as undefined?

I'm not certain it's necessary to bind "this" to displayGender because unlike toggleGender it should already be bound to the correct object by default. I believe you should be able to access this.props from displayGender just by invoking the method.

The [Handling Events](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html) section in the React docs might be helpful.